# Element not interacable

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have this error "element not interactable" When I try to click a drop down list with selenium. However in debug mode, when I inspect ( press F12 ) before the break points and I continue to run then the test is passed. So my question is Why the elements can be clicked and what should I do to prevent the situation again. Many thanks!

Comment: Just wait until element interactable, then click

Answer (score 0):

You have to add wait / delay before accessing the elements to let the elements be fully loaded on the page before accessing them.
The simplest way is to add hardcoded sleep, like

```
time.sleep(5)
```

The better way is to use explicit way implemented by expected conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note down,

1. Always launch browser in full screen mode.

   ```
   driver.maximize_window()
   ```

this **code** should be written before `driver.get()`

2. Whenever you get `element not interactable`, try to use action chains to click or `send_keys` :

something like this :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element('your web element here').click().perform()
```

3. Make sure that using Selenium, the desired web element should be in Selenium view port.

in order to resolve this, you may have to scroll down to let Selenium know where exactly the element is.